# Rally inline edit grid from custom data store

Tags: rally

I cannot figure out how to save data back to rally after it has been edited inline - I had a working version with a rallygrid simply by providing the model type, but I needed to aggregate and change the data in some cases which I did not have the flexibility to do.  Everything else should work - the one problem I am having is saving the changes a user makes in-line back to rally.

```
_createGrid: function(start, end, type, filterConfig) {
    App._newGrid(start, end, type, {
        filters : filterConfig,
        fetch   : ['FormattedID', 'Name', 'Description', 'Notes', 'Owner', 'PlannedStartDate', 'PlannedEndDate', 'c_WINListState', 'c_Department', 'Parent']
    }, true, filterConfig);
},

_newGrid: function(start, end, type, config, normalGrid, filterConfig) {
    Ext.define('WinState', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
            {name: 'value', type: 'string'}
        ]
    });

    var dataStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'WinState',
        data : [
            {value : "Off Track"},
            {value : "At Risk"},
            {value : "On Track"},
            {value : "Complete"}
        ]
    });

    Ext.define('StateEditor', {
        extend       : 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
        xtype        : 'stateeditor',
        displayField : 'value',
        store        : dataStore,
        queryMode    : 'local'
    });

    Ext.define('Department', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
            {name: 'value', type: 'string'}
        ]
    });

    var deptStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'Department',
        data : [
            {value: "x"},
            {value: "y"},
            {value: "z"},
        ]
    });

    Ext.define('DepartmentEditor', {
        extend       : 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
        xtype        : 'depteditor',
        displayField : 'value',
        store        : deptStore,
        queryMode    : 'local'
    });

    var gridId;

    if (normalGrid) {
        gridId = 'dataGrid';
    } else {
        gridId = 'detailGrid';
    }

    var parseData = [];
    Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
        model   : type,
        limit   : Infinity,
        filters  : filterConfig,
        fetch    : ['Name', 'FormattedID', 'PlannedStartDate', 'PlannedEndDate', 'Notes', 'Parent', 'Description', 'c_WINListState', 'c_Department', 'Owner']
    }).load({
        callback : function(store) {
            Ext.Array.each(store.getItems(), function(item) {
                var winOrder;

                var owner;
                if (item.Owner) {
                    owner = item.Owner._refObjectName;
                } else {
                    owner = '';
                }

                var state;
                if (item.c_WINListState) {
                    state = item.c_WINListState;
                } else {
                    state = '';
                }

                parseData.push({
                    Parent          : '' + winOrder,
                    Name            : '' + item.Name,
                    ID              : '' + item.FormattedID,
                    Scope           : '' + App._getSpan(new Date(item.PlannedStartDate), new Date(item.PlannedEndDate)),
                    Notes           : '' + item.Notes,
                    Description     : '' + item.Description,
                    WINListState    : '' + state,
                    Department      : '' + item.c_Department,
                    Owner           : '' + owner
                });
            });


            App.grid  = App.down('#displayArea').add({
                xtype             : 'rallygrid',
                id                : 'fullGrid',
                disableSelection  : true,
                showPagingToolbar : false,
                enableEditing     : true,
                store             : Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store', {
                    data     : parseData,
                    pageSize : 1000000,
                    autoLoad : true
                }),
                columnCfgs: [
                    {text: 'ID',            dataIndex: 'ID',            flex: 1},
                    {text: 'Name',          dataIndex: 'Name',          flex: 2},
                    {text: 'Notes',         dataIndex: 'Notes',         flex: 3},
                    {text: 'Description',   dataIndex: 'Description',   flex: 3, editor: 'rallytextfield'},
                    {text: 'Scope',         dataIndex: 'Scope',         flex: 1},
                    {text: 'State',         dataIndex: 'WINListState',  flex: 1, editor: 'stateeditor'},
                    {text: 'Department',    dataIndex: 'Department',    flex: 2, editor: 'depteditor'},
                    {text: 'Owner',         dataIndex: 'Owner',         flex: 1}
                ]
            });
            console.log('parseData',parseData);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the question still actual but as far as I dive into Rally SDK to create something similar
I guess you should add some listeners to your custom editors like [here](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox) in the section "Events" and update your entities using [Data Models](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/guide/data_models)

Here is quote from my conversation with support team:

> There is no built-in support for editable grid based on a custom
>   store.